# Sequelize - how to filter by association (belongsToMany)?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model lets say Post and Country. I want to filter and get Posts where country id is e.g. 1 or where country ids must be 1 and 2 in same post, how can I achieve this using Sequelize? The way I am trying below is giving me something not what I'm expecting

Many Thanks

**Post.js**

```
class Post extends Sequelize.Model {}

Post.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        text: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
    }
);

module.exports = Post;
```

**Country.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

class Country extends Sequelize.Model {}
Country.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true
    }
}, {sequelize, modelName: 'country'});

module.exports = Country;
```

**App.js**

```
Post.belongsToMany(Country, {through: "PostCountry", foreignKey: 'id'});
```

**what i'm trying**

```
 Post.findAndCountAll({
        order: [[Country, "name", "asc"]],
        include: [
            {
                model: Country,
                through: { where: { countryId: [2] } }
            }
        ],
        distinct: true,
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
    })
```

**sample output**

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalResults": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "text": "hello, world",
            "countries": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Australia",
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "New Zealand",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Singapore",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Because this was the top google hit for "sequelize filter by association", I would just like to point out the typical way to include a filter by a joined column in a sequelize query, which they call "nested column syntax" : https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, it looks like you've mixed up `through` (which shouldn't be necessary in this query) and `where` (which is necessary).  Try this:

```
Post.findAndCountAll({
        order: [[Country, "name", "asc"]],
        include: [
            {
                model: Country,
                where: { countryId : {[Op.in]: [2]}}
            }
        ],
        distinct: true,
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
    })
```

HTH

Addendum ----

To show ALL the countries, you'll need TWO joins - once to identify Posts with the some particular country, then another to identify all of their associated countries... as mentioned in [this post](http://Include%20all%20children%20if%20any%20one%20matches).  FWIW, I have not tried this with findAndCountAll, but it should work...

Comment: could I ask for one more clarification, right now the query returns the Post I need perfectly, but in the response, for countries it only returns the country that i'm filtering by and removing all other countries tied to the post. Would it be possible to have those countries be returned in the result as well? Many thanks once again

Comment: I'm very interested in the actual URL behind the "this post" link